# Polymer & performance on mobile. Is it ready for production?

Tags: performance, mobile, polymer, web-component

I am thinking of integrating Web Components / Polymer on my mobile web-app.

There are two performance major bottlenecks here (as I see it):

1. Polymer's "platform.js" size is 163KB (44KB GZipped). This is pretty big for mobile 3G networks. Polymer claims that their primary goal is performance, while in the same breath Google's [best performance practice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YV1nKLWoARQ) is first loading mobile app's critical path with minimum network requests (1 request?) + minimise this request size.
   If I only want to load non critical components using Polymer I can use [async script loading pattern](https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/). If this is not the case, I will be forced to wait for this script to be loaded until page can start render.
2. Webcomponents heavily uses html imports, which uses additional network requests. Here I found two possible solutions ([1](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/concatenating-web-components.html), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3EPIeKaDCU&feature=youtu.be) )

My only conclusion here is that Webcomponents & Polymer are not [ready for (mobile) production](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/web-components-arent-ready-production-yet/) (?)

Answer (score 5):

I am not sue what exactly you are asking but Polymer is currently at version 0.3.4 and the [polymer homepage](https://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#readiness) itself states that it is currently in “developer preview.”

Once the browser implement the platform.js features natively the polyfills will go away.

1. If you make use of any framework or javascript library you will have to pay the cost. This is unless you want to code everything in VannilaJS (which most won't anyways). So you will have to cope with this with any other library. Usually you won't only include jQuery (22 KB) but also additional libraries, so I dont't really see this as an argument against Polymer.
2. You correctly mentioned the workarounds. With SPDY/HTTP-2 the need for vulcanizing will go away, as those new HTTP protocols are much more clever with dealing with multiple resources/requests.

You can try out the [Topeka app](https://polymer-topeka.appspot.com) on your mobile browser. I think it works just fine on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

On an iPhone 5 using a very good wifi connection, the load time of that Topeka app is atrociously bad (actually for me it never got past "connecting" even when loaded). It's not necessarily the file size that's the issue, it's the polyfills which are complicated and slow to execute. Those aren't going away in browsers like Safari or IE anytime soon, so I would not call web components "ready for production" unless you can require your users to use Chrome.

There are potential web component alternatives that don't polyfill all the technologies Polymer depends on: KnockoutJS recently implemented its own version of WCs, and there is also the VanillaJS implementation. X-tag 2 is now using the Polymer polyfills, so it may not be much better than Polymer, but worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

I tired to use polymer for a chat application, and to be fair, I did not care much about their polyfills and shadow dom, I just wanted really nice collection of paper elements. I used meteor and their Blaze template engine. 
As for Polymer 0.5.5 there were **a lot of pain with shadow dom**, with browsers that don't support it. You have to be browser oriented very strictly. I ended up getting rid of polymer and using materialize ui.

## But Polymer 1.0 is now released

They made it not compatible with the 0.5 APIs, and saying that they got rid of shadow dom concepts and introduced new `shady dom`, it is aslo much faster than 0.5.5 but I don't want to make more experiments yet.